# UnsatisfiedLinkError with javaws

Tags: java, android, jnlp, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java-web-start

I am trying to use android screen cast. http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/ All the requirements that is said for installing is there..This is the error I get,

```
$ javaws androidscreencast.jnlp

$ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/i386/libdeploy.so: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1647)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1005)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.UnixConfig.loadLibDeploy(UnixConfig.java:38)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.UnixConfig.<clinit>(UnixConfig.java:26)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.ConfigFactory.newInstance(ConfigFactory.java:11)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.Config.getInstance(Config.java:662)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:678)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Main.java:119)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Main.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

What is the missing file/ path here? what can be done to fix this?

Comment: You might be better off posting to the [Google support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/androidscreencast) for the API.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson isn't it a java problem? a missing path or something?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason** :  the Server is not shut Down Properly. Hence this error came.

**Solution** : Start Task manager look for Javaw.exe with higher value of PID(Process ID) and kill that process and then start the server.

**Explanation** :  If you start task manager and look for javaw.exe you will find 2 processes with this name. One of these process is for Eclipse and other is for Server that is not closed properly. so you need to kill the Servers Javaw.exe process.

To identify this kill the process with high PID value as you can start server only after starting eclipse(unless you are using external tomcat).

Hope this helps..